# DrRacket Scheme Contract Violation expected number

Tags: recursion, scheme, apply

I'm starting to coding in Scheme and I wan't to know if a number is "abundante". A number x is "abundante" if the sum of its dividers is greater than the double of x.

So this is my code:

```
#lang scheme
(define (abundante x)
  (cond 
    ((= x 0) #f)
    ((= x 1) #f)
    ((> (apply +(divisores x)) (doble x)) #t)
    (else #f)
    )
  )


;aux functions
(define (doble x) (* x 2))

(define (divisores x)
  (cond
    ((= x 1) '(1))
    (else (cons 1 (divisores-aux x 2)))
    )
  )

(define (divisores-aux x y)
  (cond
    ((= x y) '(x))
    ((integer? (/ x y))(cons y (divisores-aux x (+ y 1))))
    (else (divisores-aux x (+ y 1)))
    )
  )
```

As you can see, I have 3 auxiliary functions:
1) Doble x: Return the double of x
2) Divisores x: Return the dividers of x
2.1) Divisores-aux x y: Check if x/y is a integer number, then goes for y+1

But I got the problem when Divisores-aux reach x = y. I want to return x because x its a divider of itself but DrRacket prints the follow error:

```
+: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: y
  argument position: 6th
  other arguments...:
```

And indicates me that the error was produced on `apply +(divisores x)`

If I return null or '() everything goes fine, but obviously I don't get the correct result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'(x)` wil not return a list with the value of `x` but the symbol `x`. It should be `(list x)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the base case of `divisores-aux`, in here:

```
'(x)
```

The above expression will return a list with the *symbol* `x` as its single member (to understand why, read about [quoting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/quote.html) in the docs). What you meant to say was this, that creates a list with the *value* of the `x` variable:

```
(list x)
```

Also, it's better to use `remainder` to test if a number is divided by another. This should fix the issues:

```
(define (divisores-aux x y)
  (cond
    ((= x y) (list x))
    ((zero? (remainder x y)) (cons y (divisores-aux x (+ y 1))))
    (else (divisores-aux x (+ y 1)))))
```

Now `abundante` works as expected:

```
(abundante 42)
=> #t
(abundante 45)
=> #f
```